# Why is Safari messing with the heights of my div?

Tags: html, css, safari, frontend, cross-browser

I just completed a challenge for FrontEnd Mentor and was texting a friend my demo link to show off/celebrate. But when I went to open the link on my phone I noticed the formatting was all messed up. I've since opened the site on Safari, and the height of the `div.selected-plan` is getting all messed up.

This is what it looks like on my machine with Chrome.
[image: Screenshot of website rendered with Chrome.]

And the distorted Safari version.
[image]

[Link to the live site](https://xenodochial-thompson-79205a.netlify.app/) so you can view the html/css.

Why is Safari distorting things and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Give below CSS to your SVG I think It Creates height

```
.music-icon {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: .25em;
    max-width: 48px;
    max-height: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Why does Safari make the icon larger? Is its box model different than Chrome?

Comment: Sometimes Chrome does not show any issue it is rectified issue but in safari, it shows what we actually do issue.